# after org-capture, how to go to the content that I saved?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I just wondering if there is a way to go to the content which saved by doing `org-capture`

I couldn't find any customizable variable so far :-/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Org provides a couple ways to jump to the most recent captured item. The `org-capture` command can be called with a `C-u C-u` prefix to jump to the last entry. For example if you have bound `org-capture` to `C-c c` you should be able to use `C-u C-u C-c c`.

By default org-capture will also set a bookmark `org-capture-last-stored` so you can jump there using standard bookmark commands. For example, the default binding `C-x r b` (`bookmark-jump`) can be used to go to the bookmark set by org.

Comment: thank you for the asnwer :-) could you let me know what does `C-u C-u` command means?  because I changed whole keybinding as well as `C-u` keybinding :-/

Comment: Aha. By default `C-u` is bound to `universal-argument`, which is used to pass an argument to an interactive command. Calling it twice passes the argument `(16)`, so the example I gave would be equivalent to evaluating `(org-capture '(16))`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html.

Comment: ```(defun after-org-capture-goto-there()
  (interactive)
  (org-capture '(16))
  )```,  you can add this simple function to `org-capture-after-finalize-hook`

Comment: If you want to immediately go to the captured item when you capture it, you can use `C-u C-c C-c` (i.e. add a prefix to `org-capture-finalize`) to complete the capture.

Answer (score 5):

You can also put `:jump-to-captured t` as a property at the end of your capture definition in `setq org-capture-templates`. It will then automatically jump to the point where your capture was created.

Answer (score 3):

There's a chapter in the manual covering this: [Capture - Refile - Archive](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-_002d-Refile-_002d-Archive.html). You can get there via `M-x org-info`, `m` (to pick from the menu), then `capture <enter>`.

The variable you need is `org-default-notes-file`. The value stored here is the file that captured notes are placed in.